# C#/ASP.NET lambda conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Somehow when I return this to my view:

```
return View(db.Properties.ToList());
```

I get 3 properties, one of which has the location value of "Oregon".

But in another method declared like this:

```
public ViewResult Browse(string location)
{
        return View(db.Properties.Where(p => p.location == location).ToList());
}
```

I get 0 properties.

I suspect the string "location" is getting converted to something strange somewhere, but I'm not sure in what way it would be getting converted. When I replace the lambda '== location' with '== "Oregon"' I still get 0 properties.

How do I fix this?

Also, is there anyway to see the intermediate SQL that gets created for debugging purposes?

EDIT: This is using entity framework.

EDIT: I'm getting slight different results now. It appears the incoming location string is empty (even though I see it in the URL). I have rewritten everything and posted it at:

[Passing string parameters MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863609/passing-string-parameters-mvc-3)

Comment: You haven't said which LINQ provider you're using, which makes it hard to help you debug it...

Comment: I believe I'm using Linq to Entities. Might be Linq to SQL. Sorry. I'm very new to C#/MVC.

Comment: @micahhoover: You need to find out which, as they have different ways of logging. If you can post some code, that would help.

Comment: Here are my using statements: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ElkDogTrader.Models; I remember installing Entity Framework with NuGet, but I didn't install Linq to SQL that way.

Comment: @micahhoover: Right, yes, that's EF.

Comment: What sort of EntityFramework? 4.0, 4.1, Do you have an EDMX? Do you have POCO classes ? If so, which code generation tool?

Answer (score 3):

I can't replicate this - I tried the following...

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new ORMTestEntities();
        var oneprop = db.Properties.Where(p => p.location == "Oregon").ToList();
        ViewBag.Oneprop = oneprop;
        return View(db.Properties.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        var db = new ORMTestEntities();
        var oneprop = db.Properties.Where(p => p.location == "Oregon").ToList();
        ViewBag.Oneprop = oneprop;
        return View("Index",db.Properties.Where(p => p.location == "Oregon").ToList());
    }
```

both of which work as expected.

having created a table thus

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Properties](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[location] [varchar](50) NULL,
[otherthing] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Properties] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[Id] ASC
 ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is using the out-of-the-box EF model generation - no T4 templates, no "Add Code Generation Item" or anything else.  I'd suggest you start from scratch and re-build one thing at a time to see where it goes wrong.

EDIT: I just added the code generation item "ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator" with no change in the results.

To answer the second part of your question, in order to see the DB queries the easiest thing is to hook up EFProf http://efprof.com/ - the 30 day trial should work for you.

Comment: You went all out trying to answer this one. I'm going to tinker around with it, but I can't mark it as "the answer" unless it gets resolved. I thought I was just doing something stupid.

Comment: (I wonder what would happen if I created the table right before I ran the lambda expression on it (like you did) ...).

Comment: I've no idea. Is this really exactly your code? No changes in capitalization or anything ? Have you set a breakpoint on the second controller method and looked at what is going on there ? Instead of returning the model to the view, put it into a variable and see what the value is. Put a breakpoint in the view and see what you get there. And try EFProf to check the generated SQL.

Comment: The reason why you didn't have the problem is because you didn't rename any parameters something other than 'id'. If you want it to be other than 'id', you have to change the routing table. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863609/passing-string-parameters-mvc-3

Comment: ha - you mean location wasn't being set at all? Red herring! That's odd because you said "When I replace the lambda '== location' with '== "Oregon"' I still get 0 properties."

Comment: Yeah it is odd. It threw me off. When I ran it again the hard coded entry started giving me a response. I'm not sure if I failed to recompile or I got mixed up reading the output or what. Anyway, underneath this is a bunch of people who sunk a lot of time in for something totally unrelated. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

[Passing string parameters MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863609/passing-string-parameters-mvc-3)

Since the parameter was not named "id" everything went bad.