# Passing string parameters MVC 3

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to pass a string parameter in MVC3.

The URL that gets generated is:

http://localhost:50164/Property/Browse/Oregon

This appears to be the Property controller class in the function "Browse" with parameter "Oregon".

The right function gets called, but the string appears to be empty.

```
        public ViewResult Browse(string location)
        {
            //counted_properties: 3 counted_properties_here: 0 
            ViewData["counted_properties"] = db.Properties.Count(); // debug    3 total
            ViewData["counted_properties_here"] = db.Properties.Where(p => p.location == "Oregon").Count(); // debug    1 (the right answer!)
//return View(db.Properties.Where(p => p.location == tmp_location).ToList());     // 0 (bad!)

            ViewData["the_location"] = location;
            int size = tmp_location.Length;     // unhandled null exception when tmp_location = location
            ViewData["location_length"] = size;
     //       return View(db.Properties.Where(p => p.location == "Oregon").ToList());     // Right! but hardcoded
            return View(db.Properties.Where(p => p.location == location).ToList());
        }
```

When I return the lambda using the hard coded string (Oregon), I get the right answer.

When I return the lambda using the parameter (string location) I get zero results.

When I try to display ViewData["the_location"] which is a direct copy of the parameter it is blank. Maybe I'm not trying to display it correctly. Here is my view:

```
Location: @Html.Encode(ViewData["the_location"] )
```

When I call location.Length I get an unhandled null exception, but this works when I call Length on a hard coded parameter like "Oregon".

It looks like somehow the string is empty, but this doesn't make sense since I see "Oregon" in the URL when it gets to the property/browse function.

I'm beginning to wonder if I am allowed to pass strings as arguments in MVC as I haven't seen any examples with string parameters.

This is a continuation of an unsolved problem:

[C#/ASP.NET lambda conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476254/c-asp-net-lamba-conversion)

By the way, I'm not trying to promote Oregon here. I've never been there. Maybe it's a good place, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your routing. Traditionally URLs like the one you give will map the value ("Oregon") to the "id" parameter, rather than the `location` parameter that you're trying to use. Either rename the parameter or change the route to use "{controller}/{action}/{location}".

Comment: That solved it. Does anyone know where to change the routing in case I had decided to go down that route?

Comment: have a look in the Global.asax

Comment: @micahhoover: Global.asax.cs will generally define the main routes. If you're using MVC Areas, you'll need to check the corresponding `AreaRegistration` class.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I wish I could vote up both your comments. EDIT: Oh, you can vote up comments now!